# How can i parse a enum value through GSon parser in android application

Tags: android, json

I am getting the response

```
{
    "returnCode": "0",
    "message": "Sucessfully get  credit card for value(1) ",
    "token": "",
    "CreditCard": {
        "class": "CreditCard",
        "id": 1,
        "bankName": "NA",
        "cardNumber": "1233435467789",
        "ccvNumber": "3455",
        "dateCreated": "2012-02-10T10:20:06Z",
        "expiryDate": "2012-02-29T18:30:00Z",
        "expiryDateStr": null,
        "lastUpdated": "2012-02-10T10:20:06Z",
        "securityCode": null,
        "type": {
            "enumType": "CreditCardType",
            "name": "Visa"
        },
        "user": {
            "class": "User",
            "id": 4
        }
    }
}
```

I can't change server code, so how do i parse it. any helped..

Answer (score 0):

your enum:

```
enum CreditCardType{
  Visa, MasterCard, Diners
}
```

and while parsing, when you reach till `type`

```
//param is JSONObject
CreditCardType card = CreditCardType.valueOf(param.getString("name"));
```